# Insert into table python

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, tuples, pymysql

I generated this array I want to insert into my table using python sql.

```
def get_guards(list3, list2, list1):
       merg_list = [(list3[i], list2[i], list1[i]) for i in range(0, len(list3))] 
       return merg_list
qs = """INSERT INTO duties (token, post, service_no) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
list1 = group_guards
list2 = zns
list3 = token_no
values = get_guards(list3, list2, list1)
cur.executemany(qs, values)
conn.commit()
```

This gives me an error

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

The list output is

```
[('GUARD_NO:0002', 'Gate A', ['09494947', '209944']), ('GUARD_NO:0002', 'Guard B', ['38394904', '44774887', '8494994']), ('GUARD_NO:0002', 'Guard C', ['8764884', 'B909876'])]
```

Comment: Do you want to insert ['09494947', '209944'] into service_no?

Comment: @vaeng yes.I want to insert in a table 'duties' with columns token, post, and service_no. In my case Guard_no:0002 is token, Gate A is post and '09494947', '209944' -service_no: ( guards for post Gate A)

Answer (score 1):

As vaeng infers: 
It seems that you want to add a list

> ['09494947', '209944']

to service_no.
SQL is not very keen in lists in the python format.
So you would have to either split your lines and add a separate entry for each value of service_no or normalize it and add the foreign key to a different table. for each service_no .